# How to find minimum time needed for Hamiltonian evolution?

Tags: quantum-state, hamiltonian-simulation

Database search can be looked upon as Hamiltonian evolution, with kinetic and
potential energy operators. Let the evolution follow the Schrodinger equation:

$$i\frac{d}{dt}|\psi⟩= H|ψ⟩$$
with $H = E|s⟩⟨s| + E|t⟩⟨t|$ and some constant $E$.
How can we find the minimum time $T$ required for the initial state $|s⟩ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{i=1}^N |i⟩ $ to evolve $N$ to the final state $|t⟩$.

Comment: So do you mean $|s\rangle$ and $|t\rangle$ have the same eigenvalue?

Comment: @ZhiboYang Yes the eigen value is going to be same

Comment: What did you try so far? Did you calculate the unitary time evolution? Apply it to the initial state?

Comment: @M.Stern On solving Schrodinger equation by considering the initial state and final state as $|s\rangle$ and $|t\rangle$ I found the expression like this as follow 
$|t\rangle = |s\rangle \exp\left\{\frac{HT}{i}\right\}$.
So should I do Tayler series expansion of the expression of exponential term?

Comment: It sounds like you are asking how long adiabatic evolution takes. This is given by the spectral gap of the Hamiltonian from start to finish.

Comment: The usual series for the exponential function also works with matrices